# Javascript issue confim message

Tags: javascript

I made a short Javascript function:

```
function confirmMessage() {
  var messages = confirm("Are you sure");
  if(messages) {
    //go trough
  }else{
    //stop, cancel the action
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href='?pagina=uitloggen'  onclick="confirmMessage()">
```

When I click cancel, it returns false and jumps to the else statement. But it doesn't stop the action! What is the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag's `onclick` should **return** the result of the event handler for it to stop propagating.

```
<a href='?pagina=uitloggen'  onclick="return confirmMessage()">
```

Comment: and if you want to use it like you are doing, you need to do `event.preventDefault()` in place of `return false`;

Comment: @techfoobar, sorry. I wasnt telling you. I was referring @ JochemTheSchoolKid. Your code is absolutely fine

Comment: @Jashwant - Ok. And you're right, you can omit `return` from the `onclick` if you do a `preventDefault()` from inside the function.